# Select files which end with certain characters

Tags: windows, file-management, selection, total-commander

Is there any way to select files which end with certain characters in Windows? I have a folder which contains a large number of pictures which have been created but with a resized size, and I'd like to get rid of them.

An example would be: `picture-150x150.jpg`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use the command line to delete all files that end with a certain string.
`del *150x150.jpg` will delete any file that ends in 150x150.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any extra software for this.

- Go to the desired folder.
- To save time and effort, use the Search box.

  [image]
- Type a word or part of a word into the Search box.

It will list all files with that part of name in the folder.